Is the use of 女の子 and 男の子 in the following meme problematic?
So in Vietnam, there's this meme that goes: "As long as you're (sexually) gratified, male or female won't matter." Someone has attempted to translate it into Japanese to something like this: "幸せであれば女の子も男の子も重要ではない".
What I want to ask is doesn't the Japanese translation sound a bit problematic considering we're talking about sexual gratification and minors? I mean, it's definitely a product of automatic translation. However, I also know that "女の子" and "男の子" could be used to refer to young adults too, but I haven't encountered "女の子も男の子も" being used to mean "male and female in general, regardless of age" like this. "女性も男性も" would sound much more natural but I have  to admit my exposure to Japanese is very limited.

Yes, 女性・男性 does sound MUCH better in this case; although it could be infered from the context that the saying refers to (an) adult person(s), so I wouldn't exactly say this is problematic, only that the translation isn't ideal. You could also use 性別{せいべつ} or 男女{だんじょ}, both for the meaning of "sex(gender)".
But 重要ではない is a bad translation, and this shows us that the person who's translated it isn't very proficient in Japanese either; I'd use 関係ない instead. And I'm pretty sure there's a better choice of word than 幸せ but nothing is comming to my mind right now.

気持ちよければ男（で）も女（で）も関係ない？

Thanks for answering. I just want to know if "女の子も男の子も" invokes any p3d0philic connotation at all if this whole sentence is uttered like some kind of "moral", stand-alone meme that is ready to be used in various situations. So without knowing the original quote and without further elaboration, changing it to like: "性欲処理のため男性も女性も関係ない" won't be problematic?

@HuỳnhTrọngNhân If there's no context, the original translation would be taken as referring to the gender of a baby. If there's enough context, 男の子/女の子 works. Either way, it has nothing to do with pedophilia. 性欲処理 sounds fairly vulgar and disrespectful to the partner regardless of gender.
